# ¿Cómo acceder a los atributos de un objeto dentro de una función en python?

Tags: object, python-3.7, objeto

Soy nuevo en la programación con python. Actualmente estoy utilizando **pycharm** para ello y luego de algunos ejemplos básicos me surgió la siguiente duda: "¿Cómo acceder a los atributos de  un método dentro de una función en python?".

En mayor detalle lo que deseo hacer es algo como esto:

```
from Triangulo import Triangulo

class Figura:

def __init__(self):
    ...

def myMethod(self, trian):
    a = trian.CalcularPerimetro()
    return a
```

Como que no me aparece el método CalcularPerimetro() del objeto **trian** luego de escribir "trian.". ¿Cómo puedo especificar que **trian** es un objeto de tipo triángulo, de forma tal que el **pycharm** pueda darme como ayuda estos métodos del objeto trian?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Figura:

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def myMethod(self, trian):
        a = trian.CalcularPerimetro()
        return a


class Triang:
    def CalcularPerimetro(self):
        return "triangulo"


IFigura = Figura()                  #instancias tu clase Figura   
print(IFigura.myMethod(Triang()))   #le mandas la clase como parametro
```